# bootstrap grid not working unless specify screen size and column size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a completely blank page other than a simple grid. Unless I specify the size and column size then I end up with three rows. So in the below if I use col or col-md then it doesn't work.

[edit]When I downloaded bootstrap it gave me 3.3.7. I've downloaded 4 and it works. How come?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                col1
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                col2
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                col3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

any ideas? thanks.

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and running of a local html file.

Comment: if you expect a class of just `col` to work then you should be using Bootstrap 4, not 3.

Comment: `I've downloaded 4 and it works. How come?` Because they're different to each other?

Comment: In BS4, they introduced [Auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) for the grid system. Bootstrap 3 doesn't have that.

Comment: Sorry, I was scratching my head because (apart from not knowing this difference) I searched google for 'bootstrap download', got to the bootstrap page and downloaded it. It didn't mention I was getting 3.3.7.

Thanks for the speedy response though.

Comment: Check out a bs3-bs4 migration guide, it will help if you're used to bs3